# why the numerical result is different (RK45)?

Tags: matlab, julia, differential-equations, runge-kutta

this is the test for equation differential using runge-kutta45:
f(x,y)= (-5*x - y/5)^1/8 + 10

[image]

why the numerical result is different? I used :

```
function Rk_JL()
 f(x,y)= (-5*x - y/5)^1/8 + 10
 tspan = 0:0.001:n
 y0 = [0.0, 1.0]
 return ODE.ode45(f, y0,tspan);
end
```

and

```
function [X1,Y1] = RK_M()
 f = @(x,y) (-5*x - y/5)^1/8 + 10;
 tspan = 0:0.001:n;
 y0 = 1
 [X1,Y1]= ode45(f,tspan,1);
end
```

Comment: Do you know how much tolerance is assumed in both cases?

Comment: cross-posted to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/tNbuR8xOGXo.

Comment: in fact, there is a relationship with the tolerance between the methods.

Comment: You are aware that `(yyy)^1/8` is the same as `(yyy)/8` and not the probably wanted `(yyy)^0.125` resp. `(yyy)^(1.0/8)`?

Answer (score 1):

The programs have slightly different default settings, such as default tolerances and stepping/rejection behavior. As such, you shouldn't expect them to be "exactly" the same.

To add to this, ODE.jl doesn't use stepsize stabilization (which any optimized library like [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl), [ODEInterface.jl](https://github.com/luchr/ODEInterface.jl), or MATLAB's library uses), so I would expect it to have vastly worse stepsize choices (according to Hairer's book, about 2x-4x less efficient just from the stepping behavior). So even if you use the same tolerances, ODE.jl will produce different results since it's not using the standard optimized algorithm.